# How to set bash readline to vi mode automatically upon login to a system?

Tags: bash, emacs, vi, readline

My team is responsible for thousands of Linux/Unix machines, so naturally the root account is "shared" amongst the admins. I prefer vi mode, others prefer emacs mode.

How can I set bash's readline to vi mode upon SSH login to any machine, without forcing everybody else to use vi mode as well?

In essence would like to have the effect of `set -o vi` after login without actually having to type it every time, and without forcing it upon everybody else (as much as emacs mode is annoying to me, vi mode is annoying to them).

I know this wouldn't be a problem if everyone would use their own accounts with sudo to execute privileged commands, but due to circumstances outside of my control this sadly isn't an option.

Comment: Do you mean you login as "root" over ssh, or do you login as a user then `su` or `sudo` to the root account?

Comment: Both. But most of the time we log in as root with keys.

Comment: If root account is «shared» how to indicate who is connected: you or other admin(s)?

Comment: That's not easy. One way is to parse sshd's log file and to see which key was used to log in. I was hoping for a client-side solution, for example a way to pass my local readline config on to the remote side or something like that, or some dark OpenSSH magic that silently executes `set -o vi` before giving me control of the shell.

Comment: Maybe you could use an Expect script on the client that ssh's into the server, send the `set -o vi` command, then switches to interactive mode.

Comment: At least the OpenSSH `sshd` sets up several environment variables which might help you determine who is on the other end. For example, `SSH_CLIENT` contains the connecting IP-address (and the outgoing/incoming port of the client as well). Fiddling with this in `~/.bashrc` might allow you to do things *just for you*.

Comment: The bounty says you're looking for a "client side solution" -- what is that? ssh on a Unix host? Putty? Hummingbird? Java SSH? Cygwin?

Comment: Local bash functions enclosing the `ssh -t $1 'set -o vi; bash'` or similar magic should do that. There is no more dark magic in OpenSSH that could do this.

Comment: I am unsure whether I understood the question .. but you could create a bashrc file specific to your name (e.g. `~/patricks_bashrc`) and ssh using `ssh -t "/bin/bash --rcfile ~/patricks_bashrc"`   and put anything you want in that

Comment: @JeffSchaller: I'm using OpenSSH on Linux on the client side

Comment: @amisax: There's way too many machines to deploy a custom bashrc to. And I'd have to redeploy it upon any change.

Comment: You mention tens of thousands of machines. Do you want to start from **one** machine and get to these machines, or do you want to be able to hop from machine to machine to machine carrying vi mode with you?

Comment: @icarus: Both. Sometimes one hop is required, sometimes twenty-seven trillion. I use chained ProxyCommands in my ~/.ssh/config file to make this more bearable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a silly way to do it, which really only works well with public-key authentication:

First, ensure that your local machine has `nc` on it.

Second, still on your local machine, make a script (I'll call it `connect-to-server`) and put it in a place your `${PATH}` knows about*:

```
#!/bin/sh
# connect-to-server
ssh -q server-hostname "touch .yourname" </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1
nc server-hostname 22
```

Next, modify the `.bashrc` on the remote system to include somewhere:

```
# partial .bashrc
if [ -f "${HOME}/.yourname" ]; then
  rm "${HOME}/.yourname"
  set -o vi
fi
```

Finally, back in your local machine, edit `~/.ssh/config` to add:

```
# partial ssh config
Host serverNickname
  Hostname server-hostname
  ProxyCommand connect-to-server
```

Downsides of this approach (and why I call it silly):

- If there is an actual proxy command needed, it becomes more complicated.
- If someone else logs in at the same time you do, there's a chance that the `.yourname` file will not yet have been deleted, in which case they get the `set -o vi` as well.
- Most importantly, if you do `ssh serverNickname command`, then `command` will run, but (since `.bashrc` is never sourced) the `.yourname` file remains, so it would be polite to have a second alias in your ssh config that does not use the pseudo-proxy.

In fact, the *only* upside of this approach is that your `ssh` command does not need to be given any extra arguments.

---

*If you don't want to have to change anything on remote systems, here's an alternative pseudo-proxy that creates a temporary `.bashrc`:

```
#!/bin/sh
# connect-to-server
ssh -q server-hostname 'ln .bashrc .bashrc.real; cat .bashrc.real <(printf "set -o vi; ln -f .bashrc.real .bashrc\n") >.bashrc.yourname; ln -f .bashrc.yourname .bashrc' </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1
nc server-hostname 22
```

This has all the same disadvantages of the other method, so you would still want a second alias in your `ssh` configuration that does not invoke the pseudo-proxy.

Comment: Very creative. Thank you for the suggestion. I use ProxyCommand extensively already (some networks / hosts require 5+ hops to reach) and this would quickly result in a configuration nightmare. Edit: Looking at all the answers I think yours comes closest.

Answer (score 4):

I'd go for:

```
ssh server -t "bash --login -o vi"
```

but it you are an admin, you can try something cleaner. For example you could use the ssh `SendEnv` option on the client side to transmit a specific variable, use `AcceptEnv` in the `sshd` configuration (server side) to accept it, and based on this, modify root's `.bashrc` file to adjust behaviour according to the value of the variable.

This implies to change the `sshd` configuration on all hosts as well as their `.bashrc`. Not exactly a "standalone" way to do, however...

Answer (score 3):

For an easy client side solution:

```
alias connect='ssh -t root@server "bash -o vi"'
```

This will fail if the root's shell initialization scripts explicitly uses `set -o emacs` or sets `EDITOR` to `emacs`, or if root's `.initrc` file invokes `emacs` key bindings.

The rest of this answer concerns server-side solutions.

---

This works when you are `ssh`-ing into the machine and then use `sudo -i`:

For your `/root/.bashrc`:

```
if [[ -n "$SUDO_USER" ]] && [[ -f /root/.bashrc-"$SUDO_USER" ]]; then
  source /root/.bashrc-"$SUDO_USER"
fi
```

This allows you to have a personal `bashrc` file called `/root/.bashrc-patrick` wherein you can do whatever you like, like `set -o vi`.

Combining this with a somewhat naive approach to picking that rc file up depending on `$SSH_CLIENT`:

```
if [[ -n "$SUDO_USER" ]]; then
  person="$SUDO_USER"
elif [[ -n "$SSH_CLIENT" ]]; then

  case "$SSH_CLIENT" in
    192.168.216.100*)  person="joe" ;;
    192.168.216.120*)  person="patrick" ;;
    192.168.216.150*)  person="lindsey" ;;
  esac

fi

if [[ -n "$person" ]] && [[ -f /root/.bashrc-"$person" ]]; then
  source /root/.bashrc-"$person"
fi
```

This obviously only works if you're connecting from the same IP address all the time...

Another approach which uses the comment field of the particular SSH key you're using, which works if you're forwarding the SSH agent to the server:

```
ssh_comment="$( ssh-add -L | grep -f /root/.ssh/authorized_keys | awk '{ print $NF '} | head -n 1 )"
```

This picks out the comment field for the key that you used to connect to the server. The `head -n 1` is there in case you happen to have several of your keys in the `authorized_keys` file.

You may then use `$ssh_comment` to pick an rc file to source, either directly as with the `$SUDO_USER` approach above (in which the comment in `$ssh_comment` may need to undergo some cleanup if it's a pathname), or via a `case` statement as with the `$SSH_CLIENT` approach.

Comment: Matching `SSH_CLIENT` and `SUDO_USER` is what I use currently, but it requires server side modification and it's not particularly reliable. I was hoping for a pure client-side solution. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to do it without modification on the server side, either:

1) Run something like

```
$ ssh user@host -t 'bash -l -o vi'
```

I don't think the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html) is too clear on that, but `-o option` is mentioned, and seems to work.

2) Use expect:

The `expect` script:

```
$ cat bashsetup.expect
#!/usr/bin/expect -f 

set user [lindex $argv 0];
set host [lindex $argv 1];

spawn ssh -l $user $host
expect "$ "
send "set -o vi\n"
interact
```

Make it executable and run:

```
$ ./bashsetup.expect user testhost
spawn ssh -l user testhost
[motd, blahblah...]
user@testhost ~$ set -o vi
user@testhost ~$
```

This assumes you can login without entering passwords (for the remote host or for your keys), otherwise the expect script would need to take that into account. But with lots of machines you're likely to already have that. Also, I *expected* for a dollar sign and a space, edit that according to your prompt: `"# "` perhaps.

Though if something printed before prompt includes those same characters, you'll need to include something more specific in the expected string.

Also, that script doesn't support giving extra arguments to `ssh`. If you're going to give an explicit command to run, you probably don't need vi-mode, but if you need say port tunneling, that might be a problem.

---

But in any case, I really think this should be solved on the target systems with separate accounts (`sudo` or just plain old UID 0). Personalised configuration would be useful for many other cases too, and in general you'd have a bunch of configuration files and environment variables you'd like to set. (Consider that the admins might not agree on the value of `$EDITOR`, or the contents of `virc` or whatever.)

Also removing users would be easier with separate accounts.

Any way of synchronising files on all the hosts would also trivially solve this by allowing you to login with something like `ssh -t user@host 'patricks_shell.sh'` or `ssh -t user@host 'bash --rcfile patrick.rc'`.

Comment: I thought of using expect, but as you already pointed out in your question the problem is matching something unique for the prompt to start `interact`. It doesn't exist, prompts may be way different, as are the motds / output from profiles. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

#### you can have a custom rc file following this guide:

[User rc File | Secure Shell: The Definitive Guide](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/ch08_04.htm)

#### or inject a command line action in your authorized_keys file:

[SSH config auto execute remote command | Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/214420/215465)